# Is it possible to tell pdflatex to terminate after the first error?

Tags: errors, pdftex

In case of a syntax error, `pdflatex` usually (in `\errorstopmode`) gets interactive and asks you what to do. I know I can press:

- **`X`** to terminate
- **`S`** to enter `\scrollmode` (continue processing without stopping if further syntax errors arise, but stop for other errors)
- **`R`** to enter `\nonstopmode` (continue processing without stopping if further errors arise)
- **`Q`** to enter `\batchmode` (continue processing without stopping if further errors arise and suppress further output to the terminal)

Apparently, only the latter three (`SRQ`) can be provided implicitly by the respecive `\...mode` commands or the `-interaction=...mode` command line option. However, what I need is a mode that mimics the implicit pressing of `X`, that is, to make the `pdflatex` process *terminate* after the first error.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `pdflatex -halt-on-error`

Comment: Oh man, that was too obvious to find. I am feeling embarrassed; it certainly is time to stop working and start weekend...

Comment: @Daniel Good weekend!