# Not inserting missing $

Tags: errors, delimiters, syntax, options

Quite often, when making simple mistakes (like using underscore outside of math mode), LaTeX (or rather tex?) attempts to insert missing math mode delimiters.

e.g. in

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
x_2
\end{document}
```

latex yields:

```
./test.tex:3: Missing $ inserted.
```

And then, instead of telling me that the underscore was not allowed, it spits out multitudes of warnings about missing delimiters etc.

Apparently the original idea was to implement some sort of error-correcting parser. However, at least in my case, this simply does not work and -worse- yields even more confusing error messages.

Is there a way enforce a strict mode that simply bails out on the first error?

Comment: [Is it possible to tell pdflatex to terminate after the first error?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/121635)

Comment: Your code is compiled by a computer. It works linearly in one direction, from the first line to the last.  It does not back up, nor does it work sideways, just forward.  When it encounters the culprit character or command it may not immediately recognize it as an error.  It may appear perfectly normal.  Sometimes it isn't until a few lines later that the computer gets confused.

Comment: Back in the olden days the computer would just 'hang'.  Now-a-days, an escape mechanism is in the code that causes the computer to, at some point, throw up it's virtual hands and give up, displaying a message as to what it thinks is the problem, which may or may not be immediately helpful.  Experience will tell you that a certain type of error message can be caused by one or a hand full of coding errors.  That is when you start to debug.  Remember a computer is nothing but a big dumb adding machine.

Comment: You might underestimate my understanding of a computer. We are basically talking about a parser encountering an unexpected token. Instead of reporting an error, it virtually inserts another token in the hopes to recover from the first error. This might or might not work at some point. I was just searching for a way to turn it off.